# Hive join set number of reducers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I need to set number of reducers while doing a join operation in Hive. I don't want to set the same number of reducers to every join job I have. How Can I mention it as an argument? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

At the top of the script file, put this:

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=128
```

Comment: This will set it for all parts of the query rather than for a specific join.  There is no way to do it on a per-join basis (at least not yet)

Comment: I need it for per join basis. I mean I have multiple join queries in my script, each having different input sizes. So I want to set high number of reducers to heavy joins and less number of reducers where join is on very less data.

Comment: I need something like this. HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -set mapred.reducer.tasks=<n> "command". So that I can run the hive command from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this currently is to split your one Hive script into multiple parts where heavy joins would be put in a different script. Then for heavy joins, you can specify high number of reducers. To execute all of these scripts in one go, you can use `hive -f` option with all the scripts listed in a shell script as shown below: 
    
    `#example of shell script RunMyHQL.sh
    $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -f /somepath/script1.hql 
    $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -f /somepath/script2.hql
    $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -f /somepath/script3.hql`

Then assign proper permissions to RunMyHQL.sh file
    
    `chmod u+x /somepath/RunMyHQL.sh`

Then execute the shell script

    `./RunMyHQL.sh`

Each of script1, script2, and script3 can contain desired number of mappers and reducers. If this needs to run at specific intervals over and over, then I suggest you implement Oozie workflow.